# Sending Ctrl-L via dbus to terminal emulator

Tags: linux, terminal, dbus, konsole

One can send text via dbus to the terminal emulator konsole as followed:

```
qdbus org.kde.konsole /Sessions/1 sendText "hello"
```

However I want to remotely clear the screen of the specified terminal window.
So I tried:

```
qdbus org.kde.konsole /Sessions/1 runCommand "clear"
```

Does partly what I want. Only problem: The screen doesn't get cleared when there is a process running.

In the terminal emulator, in this case the key combination "Ctrl + L" would do the job.

So I'm trying to send a string with escape characters for this shortcut.
Is this going to work? This, however doesn't do;

```
qdbus org.kde.konsole /Sessions/1 sendText "\033[2J"
```

(runCommand neither)

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
qdbus org.kde.konsole /Sessions/1 sendText $'\014'
```

First, to produce a character from its octal code, the syntax `"\033"` would work in C but not in Bash.

Second, while "ESC [ 2 J" is a VT100 code to Erase Screen, it work for me only if I `echo $'\033[2J'`, and that will not work if a command is running.

Third, Ctrl-L will work if a program is expecting input from a terminal (like `irb` or `python` do), but it will not work for a `while sleep 1; do echo Still running; done` loop.